# Azure AD - Using Graph API access token from Angular SPA in C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

It looks like I'm missing something fundamental when it comes to Azure AD Enterprise applications.
I have an application running as Angular SPA with a backend ASPNETCore API that have 2 separate App Registrations in Azure AD. MyAPI is exposed as a scope "access_as_user" in MySPA.
MyAPI has no authentication flow on it's own.

I want to implement delegated access MS Graph API calls through MyAPI. Currently it only runs as a daemon service with Application permissions.

MySPA can call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ without any issues and profile is returned.
I can see that the jwt has User.Read scope:

```
"scp": "openid profile User.Read email"
```

MyAPI fails the same request with the following error:

```
code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken"
message: "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."
```

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProfile([FromHeader] string authorization)
{
   var tokenFromHeader = authorization.Replace("Bearer ", "");
   return await ("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/")
      .WithOAuthBearerToken(tokenFromHeader)
      .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .GetJsonAsync();
    }
```

The JWT naturally has the scoped permission, so the audience error makes sense

```
"aud": "api://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"scp": "access_as_user"
```

How can MyAPI access MS Graph API on behalf of users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this with Graph SDK

I added the following in my startup after `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration)`

```cs
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph()
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

This allowed me to inject the service client in my API controller:

```cs
public GraphAPIController(GraphServiceClient client)
{
   this.client = client;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetProfile()
{
   return await client.Me.Request().GetAsync();
}
```